# Retrieving Data from BLL to labels

Tags: c#, list, object, label, bll

I have a problem with regards on passing value from ListPageObj to show the value on the labels.
How can I be able to get the value?

BLL

```
public List<ListPageObj> MyList(int ItemID)
        {
            return (from a in ctx.Item where a.ItemID == ItemIDselect new ListPageObj
            {
                Item1= a.Item1,
                Item2= a.Item2,
                Item3= a.Item3
            }).ToList<ListPageObj>();
        }
```

ListPageObj

```
public string Item1
    { get; set; }

    public string Item2
    { get; set; }

    public string Item3
    { get; set; }
```

aspx

```
<asp:label id="label1" runat="server" />
<asp:label id="label2" runat="server" />
<asp:label id="label3" runat="server" />
```

aspx.cs ?

```
 //code to retrieve item1, item2, item3 value from BLL
 label1.Text = ListPageObj.Item1; // gives me null value
 label2.Text = ListPageObj.Item2; // gives me null value
 label3.Text = ListPageObj.Item3; // gives me null value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspx.cs page

```
ListPageObj ObjItem = ClassName.MyList(ItemID);

label1.Text = ObjItem.Item1; 
label2.Text = ObjItem.Item2; 
label3.Text = ObjItem.Item3;
```

BLL

```
public ListPageObj MyList(int ItemID)
        {
            return (from a in ctx.Item where a.ItemID == ItemIDselect new ListPageObj
            {
                Item1= a.Item1,
                Item2= a.Item2,
                Item3= a.Item3
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: hi @harshit can you help be with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600445/update-data-from-textbox-to-bll?noredirect=1#comment23861803_16600445) it should update data. thanks.